# Restoring recently vanished Intel HDMI audio output option

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, intel-graphics, hdmi

I have a PC whose HDMI ports are connected to the Intel GPU integrated into Core i3-4010U. It's running Ubuntu 16.04 with the latest updates. (Upgrade to 18.04 is offered but fails before any packages get installed; resolving that is a whole other issue.)

Previously, HDMI audio output has been available in the Sound setting panel (and has worked). Now it no longer is available in the Sound setting panel. I've both disconnected and reconnected the HDMI cable and applied updates after last witnessing HDMI audio working, so I'm not sure if I should blame disconnecting and reconnecting the cable or if I should blame software updates. (The HDMI cable and the device at the other end of the cable are the same as before.) I haven't made any other changes that could possible affect audio. Rebooting does not resolve the problem.

`lspci` shows both what I assume to be the GPU-integrated audio device and what I assume to be the S/PDIF / analog audio device:

```
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
```

What kind of steps should I take to get the HDMI output option restored?